# Difference between function and non-capturing lambda

Tags: c++, function, lambda, linker

What are the exact differences between:

```
auto foo(int i) -> int {
  return i + 1;
}

static constexpr auto bar = +[](int i) -> int {
  return i + 1;
};
```

In terms of linking, performance, and usage? I am curious if the lambda will behave exactly like a normally declared function.

Comment: Why are you converting the lambda to a function pointer?

Comment: Maybe to generate assembly code...

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm converting it to a function pointer to try to reduce the differences an actual function and lambda could have.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo I am curious if there is some kind of technical, cross-platform specification that ensures the two are equivalent, not just on my machine.

Comment: "_What are the exact differences between:_"  ... in what context? Here are three:
https://godbolt.org/z/lxh4K5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Linking:**
`foo` is a function and has external linkage.
`bar` is a variable, its type is `int (*const)(int)`, and has internal linkage.
I don't see any consequences of this, that should be mentioned here as an important difference.

**Performance:**
In release builds both can be inlined, so there is no difference. In debug builds `bar` is slower: compilers generate more assemly code and two (instead of one) `call` instructions for `bar` ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v2qDIc)).

**Usage:**
Both can be called with the same syntax (`foo(1)` and `bar(1)`), so there is no difference.

If a lambda does not capture anyting, it behaves like a normal function.